# How to configure Elasticsearch to pull messages from Amazon SQS

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, amazon-sqs

In my current scenario , i am having ElasticSearch on a ubuntu 14.04 machine and a amazon SQS queue holding some ".json" messages in the queue. I want  to pull the messages from amazon SQS via ES so that it can use the .json messages to index it.

What should i be looking for, how exactly should i be proceeding? I am looking for something in lines of python's boto code.

NOTE: I am not interested in using logstash for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon SQS provides an API to receive messages: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSGettingStartedGuide/ReceiveMessage.html

ElasticSearch provides an API to index messages:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index-doc.html

I am not sure if ES can automatically receive messages from SQS, but one feasible solution is a simple broker between SQS and ES to receive and index.

Comment: yes, but the docs don't help much.. i am looking for something concrete on ground basis

Comment: have you tried retrieving from SQS and dump the messages to a file? then afterwards use the basic `curl` commands to index documents in ES ? via https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html. what do you have at this point?

Comment: thanks .. i am gonna try and do this... the link u shared lands up on a 404 page.. could u just repaste it ..

Comment: can you try this? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html, then access Index API

Comment: oh yes.. i got it.. i think you have pointed me in somehow a right direction

Comment: @NishantSingh what solution did you use for this ? I am looking for the same query where i need to be able to push messages from aws sqs to Elasticsearch.

Comment: @GrinlikeaCheshirecat so what you need is a simple python script which will actually pull message from SQS and index in Elasticsearch , let me  know if you get me